# Keeping floating span valign middle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, valign

I have tried a lot to keep a span valign middle. At the moment it looks like:

[image]

But I want that:

[image]

Here you can play around: [Link](http://www.bootply.com/plY5i8S6Md#)

Comment: Remove float and to the object with vertical align

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrapper{
  display:table-row;
}

.image-left{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:grey;
  }

.text-block{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-left">
  </div>
  <div class="text-block">
    <span>One does not simply css.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I need to align text, I tend to use `display: table-cell` with `vertical-align:middle` on the parent element of the span or the div where the text is inside.

But there are literally tons of ways to achieve this. I suggest you google a bit and see which one fits best in your situation. I just prefer table-cells since they auto adjust to all content in the row, and look clean.

Detailed info: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Your link didnt work btw.

Comment: Sorry the link should work now. I think thats an Bug on bootply.com

Comment: please retry. I have tried this solution but it don't solve my problem?!

Comment: Just remove the padding-left:20px from .text and you should be good to go. ;)